MongoDB partial index optimization
I have a MongoDB collection and the following query:
{
  isActive: true,
  managerId: null,
  clientId: { $ne: null }
}

I would like to optimize this query by creating an index. It looks like partial index would be a good solution:
createIndex(
  { /** @todo: specify keys */ },
  {
    partialFilterExpression: {
      isActive: true,
      managerId: null,
      clientId: {
        $type: 'string',
      }
    }
  }
)

Now I know what to put in the partialFilterExpression, but I don't quite figure out what fields should I put in the "keys" property.
My query has a fixed constant values everywhere, there is no variable parameters.
What would be the most optimal index for this kind of query?

"optimal" is the extreme already, there is no "more optimal" or "most optimal". ;)

The index expression and the query conditions must be the same { $ne: null } is different to { $type: 'string' }. I don't know whether MongoDB can utilize this index.

@UlrichEckhardt https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114272/is-more-optimal-correct-grammar

@WernfriedDomscheit you say that the index expression and the query conditions must be the same, however, the examples in MongoDB documentation doesn't reflect that. These examples show keys that don't even intersect. This what made me to ask this question in the first place. Regarding the clientId field, it can be either string or null. As far as I understand the null in MongoDB is a type on it's own, so this technique is often recommended for such cases.

@WernfriedDomscheit however, when it comes to partial index you are absolutely right. The $type trick wouldn't work here. Sadly, the query planner won't select this index for such queries.

Of course, you could create an index where the partial expression is exactly your query (and use any arbitrary key) but such index would support only this single query. I don't think that would be a smart design unless you have such specific requirements. The index in your answer is certainly a good choice.

After studying the response from @WernfriedDomscheit and some practical experiments, I've decided to stop on the following solution:
createIndex(
  {
    clientId: 1,
  },
  {
    partialFilterExpression: {
      isActive: true,
      managerId: null
    }
  }
);

Explanation:

As @WernfriedDomscheit pointed out, the $type trick won't work for the clientId field because query planner won't select such index for processing this query (confirmed by practice).

As I can't use the clientId field in the partialFilterExpression, I've just moved it to the keys property. This effectively solved an issue with the empty keys.


As I've tested out this index seems to works great for my query. However, if you know a more optimized way, please let me know.
